# How to get the project Extensions in gradle tooling?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using gradle tooling and using `projectConnection` I'm able to get connected to gradle from java. And by using the `ModelBuilder` I'm able to get the project object also in my java class.

```
ModelBuilder gradleBuilder = connection.model(GradleProject.class);
```

But this `project` object has accessibility to Tasks only. (i.e) `project.getTasks()` is available. But not `project.getExtensions()`. How to access these extensions?? Is there any other way to access the gradle `Extensions` from Java?

Edit after your response :

When I run a gradle task it will read the closures in the given file and update the values read in a static java class (`deployGradleReaderExtension.java`). Now I'm trying to read the value from extensions by

```
deployGradleReaderExtension ext = (deployGradleReaderExtension) buildResult.getGradle().getRootProject().getExtensions().getByName("serviceConf");
```

Now I'm getting the casting exception. Because gradle and java are using diff `ClassLoaders`.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to access extensions from, say, a plugin written in Java, but not from the tooling API. To achieve strong forward and backwards compatibility, the tooling API only offers a simplified view on the Gradle object model, designed to meet the needs of integrators like IDEs.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for ur response.,, I edited my question. can u pls look into it

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing there, and I also don't understand your explanation ("when I run a gradle task, ..."). You'd have to more thoroughly explain the bigger problem you are trying to solve, the solution approach, a complete example that shows all relevant code, etc. Also, the "edit" is really a new question, so you should start a new topic.