# How to access Java plugin from Gradle `ProjectConnection`?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to get to the source sets. IIUC from [How to get the project Extensions in gradle tooling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853308/how-to-get-the-project-extensions-in-gradle-tooling), there's no API that allows such access but I'm hoping I've missed something.

Answer (score 1):

See sample code at: https://github.com/foragerr/tooling-api-custom-model

I extended the example at http://gradle.org/feature-spotlight-gradle-tooling-api/ , adding a new function to custom model to expose java.main.srcDir.

run `./gradlew invocation:run` to demonstrate.

Comment: @Noel did you have a chance to test this btw?

Answer (score 0):

http://gradle.org/feature-spotlight-gradle-tooling-api/ shows how to create a `Model` that can expose a plugin's internals. https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java shows that the Java plugin doesn't implement such a model. Therefore, getting to the source sets via `ProjectConnection` isn't possible.

Comment: Project plugin information isn't exposed through tooling API either, but the spotlight link you provided creates a custom plugin to expose plugin information. Why not do the same thing for source set information?

Comment: Hmm, initially I was thinking the plugin info exposure needed to be done by the Java plugin but maybe not. It might be possible for the plugin I'm creating to expose the Java plugin stuff.

Comment: Looking at the code in that example, it would seem you should be able to use the custom plugin and a custom model to expose any information you care for, from the project object. Let me know if you want me to give it a try.

Comment: I'm don't have time right now to try it out (I've just added a TODO). If you could give it a shot, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: So, I tried doing this, but ran into an issue. Apparently you can only pass back serializable classes using the custom model and gradle SourceSetContainer isn't serializable. (The example you liked passes plugin names as strings). Is there a particular sourceset property you're interested in? Preferable something that can be expressed as a string.

Comment: For this particular case, I'm trying to get at Java main sources (ie `sourceSets.main.java`).